# MySQL "in" command

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to know how we can do this using the `IN` comparison syntax.

The current SQL query is :

```
select * from employee 
where (employeeName = 'AJAY' and month(empMonth) = month(curdate())) 
   or (employeeName ='VINAY' and month(empMonth) = month(curdate()))
```

I tried it using `IN` comparison function, but am unable to properly set the pieces. Can any one help me?

```
select * from employee 
where employeeName in ('AJAY','VINAY') 
   and month(empMonth) = month(curdate()); // ERROR.
```

I tried it in MySQL Query.

Thank You,
Sindhu

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: Your query seems 100% correct. The error is probably somewhere else.

Comment: Can you try this: `select * from employee where (employeeName in ('AJAY','VINAY')) and (month(empMonth)=month(curdate()))`

Comment: Without error message, we can't help you...

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is fine for most DBMS (data-base management systems). As far as I know it is no problem in MySQL. But some years ago I had similar problems in DB2 and also in another more exotic DBMS named "Focus".

Maybe this can help:

- Put the complete where-block into a pair of brackets.
- Inside this block put each comparison in a pair of brackets again.
- Move the IN-Comparison to the end of the where-block.

This would transform your example into this code:

```
SELECT *
FROM employee 
WHERE (
    (month(empMonth) = month(curdate())
    AND
    (employeeName IN ('AJAY','VINAY')) 
);
```